# Как реализовать кнопку "Сохранить" на Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю текстовый редактор. Дошел до кнопки «Сохранить»

Есть фрагмент кода

В заголовочном файле

```
// ...
    QPushButton *SaveButton;

private slots:
    void slotSaveClicked();
```

В реализации (конструктор)

```
    //...
    SaveButton = new QPushButton("Сохранить");
    connect(SaveButton, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSaveClicked()));
```

За классом. Описание слота

```
void MainClass::slotSaveClicked() {
    QTextDocumentWriter writer;
    writer.setFormat("odf");
    writer.setFileName("output.odf");
    writer.write(MainTextEdit->document());
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, содержимое текстового поля записывалось в файл output.odf, который создается программно.

QtGui, QTextDocumentWriter и другие заголовочные файлы поддключены. Кнопка «Сохранить» не работает. 
Ничего при ее нажатии не происходит.

При этом ошибок компилятор не выдает. Что добавить в код?

Проверяю так:

```
void MainClass::slotSaveClicked(bool slot){
    slot = false;
    if (slot == false) {
        std::cout << "Слот вызван";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Ошибка вызова слота";
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, "не работает" - ничего не говорит нам о желаемом поведении программы; во-вторых, что не работает? Слот не вызывается?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: опять таки: слот вызывается или нет?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Как это проверить? Я подключаю кнопку к слоту с помощью connect

Comment: ну и... Слот то вызывается? Чтобы проверить сделаете хотя бы вывод в консоль чтоли.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Сейчас проверю

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Слот не вызывается

Comment: значит вы соеденили не ту кнопку.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Но она одна с такими именем. может я проверил не так? Сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я не ту строку в консоль вывел... Слот вызывается

Comment: в таком случае, что возвращает write?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это функция writer, я не знаю, как ее проверить. у нее нет метода value()

Comment: серьезно? Вы пишите в qt и не знаете что у функцию в c++ есть возвращаемое значение?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Что оно есть есть я знаю, я не знаю, как его получить.

Comment: это не многим лучше

Comment: Удалите ваш тестовый слот, пока никто не видит ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема очевидна:

```
SaveButton = new QPushButton("Сохранить");
connect(SaveButton, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSaveClicked()));
```

Вы указываете, что хотите соединить кнопку с слотом `slotSaveClicked()` без аргументов.

Но тут же показываете свой слот, у которого сигнатура:

```
void MainClass::slotSaveClicked(bool slot)
```

Нестыкововка. Поменяйте сигнатуру своего слота на:

```
void MainClass::slotSaveClicked()
```

По поводу того что компилятор ничего не выдает: Вы использует старую систему соединения сигналов-слотов, т.е. подключение проверяется аж во время выполнения программы и скорее всего Вам в консоль выводится предупреждение, что сигнатуры не подходят.
Лучше использовать более современный способ подключения, который проверяется на этапе компиляции.

```
 connect(SaveButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::slotSaveClicked);
```

Comment: В комментариях он указал, что слот у него уже вызывается, там проблема с сохранением данных в файл, но из его вопроса понять в чем проблема невозможно